# EF Core - How to retrieve base class and conditionally include property on derived class

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is my model that captures the scenario of base class and derived class

**Model**

```
public class Group
{
    List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Item 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemWithResource : Item
{
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}

public class ItemWithoutResource : Item
{
}

public class Resource
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

- A **Group** has **Item**s
- Each **Item** could be an **ItemWithResource** or an **ItemWithoutResource**

I want to retrieve all items, regardless of derived type, and also include the Resource for items that are ItemWithResource

```
return await _context.Groups
    .Include(g => g.Items)
    // NEXT LINE WILL NOT WORK AS BASE CLASS ITEM DOES NOT HAVE PROPERTY 'Resource'
    .ThenInclude(i => i.Resource)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The code snippet above illustrates the problem.  How do I write a query to 'include' Resource for Items that are an ItemWithResource?

Comment: You have have to show your dbcontext too. Shown classes don' t look real at all.

Comment: @Serge - Why's that?  Which info from DbContext would help you diagnose?  They're not real.  They're just a minimal repro of the challenge.

Comment: because it is really strange that you want to get all items, but quering  groups for some reasons. And I need to see the way the relations are configured in order to understan where are children and where are parents.

Comment: Group is the aggregate that will manage all options (both with and without a resource), so my query is based on retrieving the Group aggregate.

Comment: Would it be just easier to retrieve items from a item dbset?

Comment: @Serge ... Not if Group is managing my invariants.

Comment: this is why the relations should be shown, in order not only you could understand how it works. I can not see how group and item is related, no foreign keys, no third tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
...
.ThenInclude( i => ( i as ItemWithResource ).Resource )
...
```

Comment: not tried that yet, but figured that if `i` is not an `ItemWithResource` then the result would be null and I'd get a null reference exception when query was enumerating an `ItemWithoutResource` and we try to access the `Resource` property.  I'll give it a go, though.

Comment: @NeilW EF uses the expression to bulid SQL statements, it's not actually executed

Comment: A code-only answer doesn't get less code-only just because you preface it with "try", but it does get less convincingly authoritative. Do please explain your codes; people will continue to come across your answer for years, seeking to benefit from others' wisdom rather than engage in a "code by what N people's trial and error suggestions were"..

Comment: Ah, cool.  Hope to give you a tick very shortly ;-)